# Specifying different error messages for different composite components

Tags: localization, jsf-2, composite-component

Is there a way to have REQUIRED messages for different kinds of composite components?

I'd like to be able to say something like the following in a message bundle

```
javax.faces.component.UIInput.REQUIRED=Please enter a value for {0}
com.anon.sandbox.jsf.component.NameField.REQUIRED=ENTER A {} OR DIE
com.anon.sandbox.jsf.component.EmailField.REQUIRED=You forgot to enter a {0} address
```

I could do this by implementing custom validators for each kind of input field, but given that the only behaviour I want to customise is the error message this seems like overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `requiredMessage` attribute to specify them.

```
<h:inputText ... requiredMessage="#{cc.resourceBundleMap.requiredMessage}" />
```

For the case you didn't knew that, the `#{cc.resourceBundleMap}` refers the composite component specific resource bundle which is identified by a `.properties` file with the same filename as the composite component in the same folder.

So, imagine that you've a composite component file `foo.xhtml`, then you can specify the localized messages in `foo.properties` (and consequently `foo_en.properties`, `foo_es.properties`, etc) which reside in the very same folder. Those localized messages are then available by the aforementioned `#{cc.resourceBundleMap}`.

Comment: perfect - I didnt know you could have a message bundle per component. Thanks.