# How to parameterize requiredMessage attribute in composite component?

Tags: localization, jsf-2, composite-component

BalusC provided a good answer to a question about how to set messages per composite component. [Specifying different error messages for different composite components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9247124/specifying-different-error-messages-for-different-composite-components/9248743#comment11658784_9248743)
The answer involved using per component resource bundles.

Ive applied this approach but when I use `{0}` in the message to specify the current component label as part of the message, the `{0}` is rendered as is in my error, rather than being resolved. Is this resolution of labels available when I use this approach? Or do I have to manually build up the error message in the composite component? e.g.

```
requiredMessage="#{cc.resourceBundleMap.requiredMessage} #{cc.attrs.prefix} #{cc.attrs.label}"
```

I guess the deeper question is how can I have parameterised message strings in my resource bundle? Will I need to build some kind of custom message resolver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the `requiredMessage` (and `validatorMessage` and `converterMessage`) attribues are not parameterizable by default. I think it would make little sense anyway as they are tied to a *specific* component in particular. A composite component does usually not contain a multiple of the *same* components. You would need to specify separate messages for every individual component.

It's in theory however possible to [create a custom EL function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079978/how-to-create-a-custom-el-function/7080174#7080174) which does the message formatting job. The method would look something like this:

```
public static String format(String message, Object argument1, Object argument2) {
    return MessageFormat.format(message, argument1, argument2);
}
```

which is to be used something like this:

```
requiredMessage="#{util:format(cc.resourceBundleMap.requiredMessage, cc.attrs.prefix, cc.attrs.label)}"
```

The only disadvantage is that you can't create EL functions which can take varargs. This is a limitation of the EL specification. So if you intend to be able to pass variable arguments, you'd need to create a separate EL function and a Java method for every possible amount of arguments needed.

As a completely different alternative, you could create a custom `Validator` and attach it to the particular input component. You can even put the validator method straight in the "backing component" which is associated with the composite component by `<cc:interface componentType>`. If you remove the `required` attribute, then this validator will immediately be invoked where you've the freedom to compose messages the way you want.

E.g.

```
<h:inputText id="foo" validator="#{cc.validateFoo}" requiredMessage="#{cc.resourceBundleMap.requiredMessage}" />
```

with

```
public void validateFoo(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
    if (value == null || value.toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
        String requiredMessage = (String) component.getAttributes().get("requiredMessage");
        String prefix = (String) getAttributes().get("prefix");
        String label = (String) getAttributes().get("label");
        throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
            MessageFormat.format(requiredMessage, prefix, label), null));
    }
}
```

Comment: the custom validator approach on a backing component is the way to again. Yet again youve surpassed expectations - thank you.