# how to send parameters to properties file if i use attribute requiredMessage of inputText

Tags: jsf, primefaces

In jsf according to what I read I can replace parameters in a resource bundle string using

```
<h:outputFormat value="#{msg['message.param2']}"> 
   <f:param value="param0" /> 
   <f:param value="param1" /> 
</h:outputFormat>
```

My problem is I am working with a primefaces tag and I need to use the attribute `requiredMessage` of `inputText`, similar to this:

```
<p:inputText value="#{cteYDetalleMb.cteEnCaptura.nombreComercial}" style="width: 50em" required="true" 
             requiredMessage="#{msg['validacion.datosRequeridos']}" />
```

My message to `validacion.datosRequeridos` is requiring a parameter and the example working above is different. How can i resolve this, i try to use `<f:param>` but it does not work.

Comment: I think you can find the solution here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280915/how-to-parameterize-requiredmessage-attribute-in-composite-component

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is creating a [custom EL function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079978/how-to-create-a-custom-el-function/) so that you can end up like follows:

```
<p:inputText ... requiredMessage="#{my:format(msg['validacion.datosRequeridos'], 'param0', 'param1')}" />
```

You could also create a custom UI component which extends `<h:outputFormat>` and captures the output and stores it in a variable in the EL scope:

```
<my:outputFormat value="#{msg['message.param2']}" var="requiredMessage"> 
   <f:param value="param0" /> 
   <f:param value="param1" /> 
</my:outputFormat> 
<p:inputText ... requiredMessage="#{requiredMessage}" />
```

Both approaches are available in JSF utility library [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) in flavor of [`of:format2()`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/functions/Strings) and [`<o:outputFormat>`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/outputFormat) respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Not the best solution but You can override all default required message with this line: javax.faces.component.UIInput.REQUIRED = new required message. label:{0}
The parameter is the label attribute of the inputText.

Or you can create a backingbean method. It reads the message from the bundle.

```
   <p:inputText value="#{cteYDetalleMb.cteEnCaptura.nombreComercial}" style="width: 50em" required="true" requiredMessage="#{controller.getRequiredMessage(param)}"/>
```

You can use these helper methods to reading messages from the controllers.

```
public static String getMessage(String key) {
        FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        String mb = fc.getApplication().getMessageBundle();
        ResourceBundle resourceBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle(mb, fc.getViewRoot().getLocale());
        return resourceBundle.getString(key);
    }

    public static String getMessage(String key, String params[]) {
        MessageFormat messageFormat = new MessageFormat(getMessage(key), FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getLocale());
        return messageFormat.format(params);
    }
```